# Android: Highlight an item from List on setSelecton

Tags: android, android-listview, css-selectors

I have a ListView & listselector.xml. Initially I set the item using setSeletion(position). But with this code the item doesn't get highlighted. It gets highlighted only when I click on an item.

```
        ArrayAdapter<String> ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems);
    timeListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listList);
    timeListView.setAdapter(ad);
    timeListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);      
    timeListView.setSelector(R.drawable.listselector);
    timeListView.setSelection(toSelectPos);

     ============================= 
     XML      
     <ListView android:id="@+id/listList" android:layout_width="match_parent"    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:dividerHeight="1dp" >
```

listselector.xml code

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <!-- listselector.xml  -->
     <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
<!-- Selected -->
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/focused"/>

<!-- Pressed -->
<item android:state_selected="true" android:state_focused="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/selected" />     
      </selector>
```

The above code highlights full listview, I only want to highlight(change bg color) of the item. For that I believe I will have to create another xml for the item and set selector properties for the item & not list as done above. Correct me if am wrong.

The point is, in anyway only the selected item on click and on setSelection should be changed. With the above code, it doesn't change on setSelection, how to make that happen.

I looked in other Qs, but couldn't find the point I am looking for, so pls don't mark it as a duplicate for other Qs.

Thanks

Comment: do you want multiple selection or single selection ??

Comment: @AndroidCoader, single selection only

Comment: setSeletion(position) Sets the currently selected item. If in touch mode, the item will not be selected but it will still be positioned appropriately. If the specified selection position is less than 0, then the item at position 0 will be selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you probably already have seen in some answers here on stack-overflow, you can not put a View selected because it is implemented so that the User Interface has to be always in touch mode as you can see [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.pt/2008/12/touch-mode.html)
However, there are some workarounds That you can do.

You can set your ListView onItemClick with the following listener:

```
    OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int pos, long id) {

    if (v == lastSelectedView) {

    v.setBackgroundResource(0);
    lastSelectedView = null;

    } else if (v != lastSelectedView) {

    

    if (lastSelectedView != null)

        lastSelectedView
            .setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.transparent);

    lastSelectedView = v;

    v.setBackgroundDrawable(v.getContext().getResources()
        .getDrawable(R.drawable.some_row_background));
    }
}

};
```

In this, you will color the `listview` item as you want. However, there is a catch. **The recycling of *views* will mark another *view* if you scroll down or up**. You can "deselect" the view on a scroll or find a way to tag the view.

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that whether this is right way or not but below solution i find from support-v4 examples's fragment demo.

Make check-able custom layout & use this layout for your list's row

```
public class CheckableLayout extends LinearLayout implements Checkable {
    private boolean mChecked;

    public CheckableLayout (Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CheckableLayout (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        mChecked = checked;
        // set the custom background image/color
        setBackgroundResource(checked ? R.drawable.category_item_row_selected
                : R.drawable.custom_category_item_row);
    }

    public boolean isChecked() {
        return mChecked;
    }

    public void toggle() {
        setChecked(!mChecked);
    }

}
```

Define your listview as single choice mode like `YOUR_LISTVIEW.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);`

on click of row(**`inside OnItemClickListener`**) you have to set that row as checked like
`YOUR_LISTVIEW.setItemChecked(index, true);`

Thats it

Comment: this will give me a checkbox & I don't want any checks - just plain list.

Comment: did you make your own adapter for listview ?? Please try to make your own listview adapter and implement my answer.

Comment: @Tvd Please check https://github.com/vimalrajpara2006/ListView-with-Selected-Row project which works fine for me for single selection.